# Executing command in cmd and showing output in jTextArea of swing GUI application

Tags: java

I am developing a swing gui application in which i want to execute some cmd commands and show their output in a jTextArea and i also want to enter values asked during program execution in a jTextField. Plase provide some code which can help me to achive my goal.

Comment: what have you achieved so far?

Comment: I agree with nansen, it would be good to see the code you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should get you started with executing cmd commands from java and capturing their output:

```
import java.io.InputStream;

public class CmdProxy {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C \"dir \\ \"");
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();

        // NOTE: this is not the most elegant way to extract content from the
        // input stream
        int i = -1;
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        while ((i = is.read()) != -1) {
            buf.append((char)i);
        }

        proc.waitFor();

        System.out.println(buf.toString());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Try it in your sandbox and see what happens.  Note that the /C option ensures the cmd process terminates after it is done handling the command arguments we passed (in this case, "dir \ ").  In your case you want to exec "cmd /C \"" + whateverUserSpecified + "\"".  Obviously, I'm assuming you're programming in/for a Window's environment.  I'll let you or someone else figure out the GUI code.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. That code was fine but in my case i used the above code inside button click event, on the click